# ggplot2 legend labels not changing

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I've been searching for an answer to why my legend labels aren't changing. so far, labs() is the only way I've managed to change the title. scale_fill_discreate/manual() don't seem to work.

Any ideas?

```
ggplot(na.omit(VMSdat), aes(x = mach_type, fill=mach_type, y= interest_lvl)) +
  labs(title = "Average Level of Interest in Studio machines by  Medical\nand Vetrinarian School students", x = "Machine Type", y = "Level of Interest")+
  labs(fill="Machine Type")+
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Machine type", labels=c("CNC milling", "Die Cutter", "Electronics", "3D Printing","3D Scanning", "Vacuum Former", "Virtual Reality"))+
  facet_wrap(~schoolName)+
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="summary", fun.y="mean")+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(.2,5)) +
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=12))+ 
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size=12), legend.text=element_text(size=11))+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

[image: Machine interest graph]

Comment: You do not define any colors in `scale_`. In order to help efficiently you may add a minimum reproducible example. How this can be done is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hello @fuskerqq, as mentioned by MarBlo, scale_ won't work for changing titles. You can try xlab("Machine Type") and ylab("Level of Interest").

Comment: You have a second `scale_fill` (`scale_fill_manual` and `scale_fill_brewer`) - if you remove `scale_fill_brewer` and add colors/palette through `values` in `scale_fill_manual` does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Ben, you have two `scale_fill...` function in your code. So, it seems that one is replacing what the first one is doing.
So, a possible solution is to merge them and pass all arguments in `scale_fill_brewer`.

Without a reproducible example of your dataset, it's difficult to be sure that this solution will perfectly work for your data. Here, I'm using the internal dataset `iris` to show how to change labels and name while using `scale_fill_brewer`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1",
                    labels = c("A","B","C"),
                    name = "New Title")
```

And you get:
[image]

so, based on your code, you should get the correct plot by doing:

```r
ggplot(na.omit(VMSdat), aes(x = mach_type, fill=mach_type, y= interest_lvl)) +
  labs(title = "Average Level of Interest in Studio machines by  Medical\nand Vetrinarian School students", x = "Machine Type", y = "Level of Interest")+
  labs(fill="Machine Type")+
  facet_wrap(~schoolName)+
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="summary", fun.y="mean")+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(.2,5)) +
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=12))+ 
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size=12), legend.text=element_text(size=11))+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1",
                    name = "Machine type", 
                    labels=c("CNC milling", "Die Cutter", "Electronics", "3D Printing","3D Scanning", "Vacuum Former", "Virtual Reality"))
```

If this is not working for you, please consider providing a reproducible example of your dataset (see here: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example))

Comment: thank you for clarifying this! I completely forgot I had the scale_fill_brewer in there.